# react hot loader not working with express

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, webpack, react-hot-loader

I am using react-hot-loader and webpack-hot-middleware with express for live reload but it is not working. webpack listens for the changes but is not shown on the browser. Have i missed something?

**webpack-config.js**

```
if (!process.env.NODE_ENV) {
 process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development'
}

const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

const VENDOR_LIBS = [
    'react', 'react-dom', 'redux', 'react-redux',
    'react-router', 'react-router-redux', 'lodash',
    'express'
];

const entryPath = path.join(__dirname, 'src/index.js');

const config = {
  entry: {
    bundle: isDevelopment ? [
                            'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
                            'react-hot-loader/patch',
                            entryPath
                          ] : entryPath,
    vendor: isDevelopment ? [
        'react-hot-loader/patch',
        VENDOR_LIBS
    ] : VENDOR_LIBS,
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: isDevelopment ? '[name].[hash].js' : '[name].[chunkhash].js',
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          loader: 'css-loader'
        }),
        test: /\.css$/,
      },
      {
        use: ['babel-loader'],
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(isDevelopment ? 'development' : 'production')
      }
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: 'src/index.html',
      minify: {
        removeComments: false,
        collapseWhitespace: false,
      }
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('style.css'),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      names: ['vendor', 'manifest']
    }),
  ],
};
isDevelopment && config.plugins.push(new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin());
!isDevelopment && config.plugins.push(
        new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
          output: {
            comments: false,
            screw_ie8: true
          },
        })
    );
module.exports = config;
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "pre-start": "webpack",
    "start-dev": "node server.js --development",
    "start-prod": "rimraf dist && webpack && node server.js --production"
  },
```

**server.js**

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  console.log('DEVOLOPMENT ENVIRONMENT: Turning on WebPack Middleware...');
  const webpack = require('webpack');
  const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config');

  const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

  app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
    noInfo: true,
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
    contentBase: './dist/',
    stats: {
      colors: true,
      'errors-only': true
    }
  }));

  app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler));
} else {

  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
}

app.get('*', function (request, response) {

  response.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html');
});

app.listen(port);

console.log(`server started on port: ${port}`);
```

I am not sure, but, is it problem due to chunkhash?

**UPDATE**

**index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <AppContainer>
    <Root store={store} history={history} />
  </AppContainer>
  , document.querySelector('#app'));

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./components/root', () => {
    ReactDOM.render(
      <AppContainer>
        <Root store={store} history={history} />
      </AppContainer>
      , document.querySelector('#app'));
  });
}
```

Comment: Try removing `hot: true` from `server.js`

Comment: sorry it did not work

Comment: What operating system are you using? Also does the console in your browser say "[HMR] Connected" or something like that?

Comment: Ubuntu, it is. No i dont see any HMR in console.

Comment: I have created a repo. https://github.com/Tushant/pogimon

Comment: after i change [name].[hash].js for development, the console showed me HMR connected but an error of <Provider> does not support changing `store` on the fly. It is most likely that you see this error because you updated to Redux 2.x and React Redux 2.x which no longer hot reload reducers automatically.

Comment: webpack-dev-server works but not react-hot-loader